# Java reflect illegalAccessException on public abstract super class

Tags: java, reflection, abstract-class, illegalaccessexception

I have been given an abstract class:

```
public abstract FooPACImpl {
    ...
}
```

And two autogenerated subclasses:

```
public replyTypeFooPAC extends FooPACImpl {
    ...
}
public requestTypeFooPAC extends FooPACImpl {
    ...
}
```

And an API for creating a network pattern (request/reply) that uses a request Type and a reply Type (A and B are expected to be auto-generated sub-classes of FooPACImpl like the above):

```
Replier<A, B> get_simple_replier (
    String topic, 
    Object<A> requestType, 
    Object<B> replyType) {...}

Requester<A, B> get_simple_requester (
    String topic, 
    Object<A> requestType, 
    Object<B> replyType) {...}
```

I pull the topic string, and the string names of the two types A and B from an XML stub:

```
<rr>
    <topic>MyReqRepTopic</topic>
    <reqtype>foo.bar.baz.myReqTypeFooPAC</reqtype>
    <replytype>foo.bar.baz.myReplyTypeFooPAC</replytype>
</rr>
```

Apparently, reflection in Java can't handle directly a "public abstract" super class?

```
FooPACImpl foopa = (FooPACImpl) Class.forName(reqtypeName).newInstance();
```

results in

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class foo.bar.fnorb.ServiceSupport \
    can not access a member of class foo.bar.baz.myReqTypeFooPAC with \
    modifiers "protected"
```

1) Why "with modifiers 'protected'"?  FooPACImpl.getClass().getModifiers returns "public abstract"

2) Is this exception thrown because the class is abstract? or does it have to do with a possible constructor 'protected FooPACImpl () { };'?

3) And, is this even achievable? My understanding is that if you subclass AA with BB, you can use AA where a BB is expected, since BB will have anything that AA is expected to have (methods, fields, etc).  Although, it's been awhile.  I may be a bit hazy on the particulars of inheritance in java.

Thanks for any points/pointers, and a yes/no answer for #3 is sufficient.  In the case of a 'no', hints to how it could be implemented without reflection.  I do have access to the code generator templates for the autogenerated stuff, if that helps.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a short but complete example demonstrating the problem - ideally with conventional class names, too...

Comment: The error mentions a class foo.bar.fnorb.ServiceSupport, is this the class where you try to do the instantiation?

Comment: I think this error might occur if the constructor of class foo.bar.baz.myReqTypeFooPAC is protected. You mention the class is public, but its constructor might be protected.

Comment: @KoenWeyn : You nailed it -- the class was public, the ctor of the subclass was protected.  Correct, ServiceSupport is the class where I'm doing the reflection in.

Comment: @JonSkeet : what's the local definition of a conventional class name?

Comment: @rip...: One that follows [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: I had a long comment that stated i.a., I used foo. etc as people had the tendency to focus on minutia that -- whether it was the done thing or not -- had no bearing on the answer.  I deleted that and asked "what's the local definition of a conventional class name" because I didn't really understand the context for the comment.  

Near as I can figure, the "class name" fail was I used lower-case initial on the class names of the two FooPAC examples, and that I didn't use com. or aq. and instead relied on the 'foo' metasyntactic particle. Any others before I fix the OP?

Answer (score 2):

In the auto-generated sub-classes of FooPACImpl, there were two protected constructors:

```
protected myReqTypeFooPAC() {
    super(...);
}

protected myReqTypeFooPAC(boolean b) {
    super(..., b, ...); 
}
```

I was looking for the problem in the parent class, but it turned out to be the constructor thing.  Changing those to public allowed the code to run as expected, which I can do either using reflection? or by changing the codegen templates...